# Animate a marker to emulate user location (like Apple's MapKit)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to a animate a marker's icon so it will resemple Apple's and Google's map kits user location, that blinking dot. I could use a gif as a marker's icon but looks kind a ugly!.

[image]

My marker's icon consist of:

```
var markerIcon= {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 7,
    strokeColor: '#393'
  };
```

and the marker itself:

```
function setlocation(lat,lng,zom){
         var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        map.setCenter(myLatlng);
        map.setZoom(zom);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
    icon:markerIcon,
    optimized:true

  });
```

How can i animate the above marker so let's say it will turn from `#393`(green) to white and back again and let it loop for ever.

Any help how to make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change marker icon using `setIcon()` inside, for example `setInterval()`. Something like:

```
var isGreen = true;

var greenIcon = 'green.png';
var redIcon   = 'red.png';

...
// create and place your marker
...

    setInterval(function() {
        if (isGreen) {
            isGreen = false;
            marker.setIcon(redIcon);
        } else {
            isGreen = true;
            marker.setIcon(greenIcon);
        }
    }, 1500);
```